# Cubic addition and differentiablility

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

It came to my thought that if we define $a\oplus b = (a^3 + b^3)^{\frac13}$ then $\Bbb R$ endowed with $\oplus$ and $\cdot$ the latter being the usual multiplication is a field, with usual $0$ and $1$ being the zero and the unity of this field respectively. Not really knowing what to do next with this, I decided to check how will new derivatives be different from the old ones. If I am not mistaken, it holds that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x\oplus h)\ominus f(x)}{h} = \left(f'(x)\frac{f^2(x)}{x^2}\right)^{\frac13}
$$
if $x\neq 0$, while the direct evaluation of the limit when $x = 0$ gives that indeed it is infinite unless $f(0) = 0$. In the latter case we get the new derivative (namely, the limit) being exactly the old derivative $f'(0)$. This looks very odd to me: why $0$ should be any special point of this field?

So my questions are:

1. Did I make a mistake somewhere? If yes, please point me to it.
2. If not, why in this new field differentiability at $0$ is something special?

Comment: If you plot $x^{1/3}$, do you see anything special at $x=0$? Hint: look at the slope of the tangent

Comment: @Andrei it is vertical and the derivative is infinite, but I do not see, how this is relevant. First, if you consider $(x^3)^{\frac13}$ then you won't see this. Second, you may forget about the usual $+$ and consider $\oplus$ as the addition for your field. From that point of view it is not clear why derivative defined by $\oplus$ exist at $0$ only if $f(0) 0$, while defined by $+$ may exist there even if $f(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Andrei to add another point against your argument, if I define $a\oplus b := (a^{\frac13} + b^{\frac13})^3$, things with derivatives are even worse, even though we get a field again.

Comment: Maybe look at Michael Grossman and Robert Katz's **Non-Newtonian Calculus** (1972, viii + 94 pages), which I would guess is available somewhere on the internet by now (I have a copy of the November 1979 7th printing), and the non-trivial amount of other writing by these authors and other people on this topic (e.g. see [this website](https://sites.google.com/site/nonnewtoniancalculus/Home) and [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/281516/15780)).

Comment: For general $+_φ$ defined by $x+_φy=φ^{-1}(φ(x)+φ(y))$ where $φ:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism and $φ(0)=0$, this issue also arises if $φ'(0)=0$. Although $φ$ being a diffeomorphism ensures well-behavedness of derivation.

Comment: @Saad: when you say that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, you mean that it is differentiable in the $+$-field, right? Why would that $+$ be some kind of a benchmark for $+_\varphi$? That's my whole point, how can we distinguish $+$ from $+_\varphi$ if both of them just provide us with the field?

Comment: @Ilya Yes to the first question. As for the distinctions between $+$ and $+_φ$, I may post an answer after furthur thought, but a conspicuous one is that $a(x+_φy)=ax+_φay$ usually fails to be true, so it's not a linear space.

Comment: @Saad it works in my case though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis of the Limit**

When $x\ne0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\color{#C00}{(x\oplus h)}-\color{#090}{x}}{h^3}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x\left(\color{#C00}{\left(1+\frac{h^3}{x^3}\right)^{1/3}}-\color{#090}{1}\right)}{h^3}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac1{3x^2}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: definition of $\oplus$
$\text{(1b)}$: Binomial Theorem

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x\oplus h)-f(x)}{h^3}
&=\color{#C00}{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x\oplus h)-f(x)}{(x\oplus h)-x}}\color{#090}{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x\oplus h)-x}{h^3}}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{\color{#C00}{f'(x)}}{\color{#090}{3x^2}}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: limit of a product
$\text{(2b)}$: definition of derivative and $(1)$

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x\oplus h)\ominus f(x)}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{f(x\oplus h)^3-f(x)^3}{h^3}\right)^{1/3}\tag{3a}\\
&=\left(\color{#C00}{\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{f(x\oplus h)^3-f(x)^3}{f(x\oplus h)-f(x)}}}\color{#090}{\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x\oplus h)-f(x)}{h^3}}\right)^{1/3}\tag{3b}\\
&=\left(\color{#C00}{3f(x)^2}\color{#090}{\frac{f'(x)}{3x^2}}\right)^{1/3}\tag{3c}\\
&=\left(f'(x)\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\right)^{1/3}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: definition of $\ominus$
$\text{(3b)}$: limit of a product
$\text{(3c)}$: derivative of $x^3$ and $(2)$
$\text{(3d)}$: rearrange

$(3)$ is as stated in the question.

---

When $x=0$, there are three cases:

**$\boldsymbol{f(0)=0}$:**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x\oplus h)\ominus f(x)}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{f(h)^3-f(0)^3}{h^3}\right)^{1/3}\tag{4a}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}\tag{4b}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\tag{4c}\\[6pt]
&=f'(0)\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: $0\oplus h=h$ and apply $\ominus$
$\text{(4b)}$: apply $f(0)=0$ and simplify
$\text{(4c)}$: apply $f(0)=0$
$\text{(4d)}$: definition of derivative

$(4)$ is as stated in the question, but there is another case where the limit exists.

**$\boldsymbol{f(0)\ne0}$, but $\boldsymbol{f'(0)=f''(0)=0}$**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x\oplus h)\ominus f(x)}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{f(h)^3-f(0)^3}{h^3}\right)^{1/3}\tag{5a}\\
&=\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)^3-f(0)^3}{f(h)-f(0)}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h^3}\right)^{1/3}\tag{5b}\\
&=\left(3f(0)^2\frac{f'''(0)}6\right)^{1/3}\tag{5c}\\
&=\left(\frac{f(0)^2f'''(0)}2\right)^{1/3}\tag{5d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: $0\oplus h=h$ and apply $\ominus$
$\text{(5b)}$: limit of a product
$\text{(5c)}$: apply L'Hôpital thrice
$\text{(5d)}$: simplify

**$\boldsymbol{f(0)\ne0}$ and $\boldsymbol{f'(0)\ne0}$ or $\boldsymbol{f''(0)\ne0}$**

Same argument as $(5)$, but one of the applications of L'Hôpital gives an infinite limit.

---

**Answers to the Questions**

> 1. Did I make a mistake somewhere? If yes, please point me to it.

Not really a mistake, but an omission. There is a case where $f(0)\ne0$ and yet the limit exists. One example would be $e^{x^3}$.

> 2. If not, why in this new field differentiability at 0 is something special?

The difficulty arises because the functions of which we are taking derivatives with cubic addition and subtraction use the standard addition and subtraction in computing their values. When differentiating a function near $0$, $f$ can carry the large changes from cubic addition, $(x\oplus\Delta x)-x$, near $0$ to $f(0)$. If $f(0)\not\approx0$, cubic subtraction, $(f+\Delta f)\ominus f$, cannot undo these large changes, resulting in a large derivative.

Consider how the argument to the function is incremented by cubic addition
$$
\begin{align}
(x\oplus\Delta x)-x
&=\left(x^3+\Delta x^3\right)^{1/3}-x\tag{6a}\\[6pt]
&=x\left(\left(1+\frac{\Delta x^3}{x^3}\right)^{1/3}-1\right)\tag{6b}\\
&\approx\frac13\frac{\Delta x^3}{x^2}\tag{6c}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\Delta f\approx f'\frac{\Delta x^3}{3x^2}$. This is big if $x$ is close to $0$.

Next, consider how the cubic difference measures the change in $f$
$$
\begin{align}
(f+\Delta f)\ominus f
&=\left((f+\Delta f)^3-f^3\right)^{1/3}\tag{7a}\\
&=f\left(\left(1+\frac{\Delta f}{f}\right)^3-1\right)^{1/3}\tag{7b}\\
&\approx\left(3f^2\Delta f\right)^{1/3}\tag{7c}
\end{align}
$$
Plugging the $\Delta f$ from $(6)$ into $(7)$ gives $\left(f'\frac{f^2}{x^2}\right)^{1/3}\Delta x$, which matches the formula in $(3)$ (which is good).

If $f(0)\not\approx0$, the $f(x)^2$ in $\text{(7c)}$ cannot compensate for $\frac1{x^2}$ in $\text{(6c)}$.

Comment: That explains! So, no necessary conditions on $f(0)$ for $f$ to be $\oplus$-differentiable. That was my main concern. Conditions on $f'$ and higher $+$-derivatives at that point do not matter, as that is simply some other field.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\D{\mathscr{D}}\def\H{\mathscr{H}}\def\R{\mathbb{R}}\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}$All the terms in this answer are in the classic sense unless specified otherwise.

Define\begin{align*}
\H &= \{φ: \R → \R \mid φ\ \text{is an increasing homeomorphism},\ φ(0) = 0\},\\
\D_0 &= \{φ \in \H \mid φ\ \text{is derivable on}\ \R^*,\ φ'(x) ≠ 0\ (\forall x ≠ 0)\},\\
\D &= \{φ \in \H \mid φ\ \text{is a diffeomorphism}\},
\end{align*}
and for any $φ \in \H$, define\begin{gather*}
x +_φ y = φ^{-1}(φ(x) + φ(y)),\\
D_φ f(x) = \lim_{h → 0} \frac{1}{h} (f(x +_φ h) -_φ f(x)).
\end{gather*}
Note that the metric induced by $+_φ$, i.e.$$
d_φ(x, y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} x -_φ y; & x \geqslant y\\
y -_φ x; & x < y \end{array} \right\} = φ^{-1}(|φ(x) - φ(y)|),
$$
is equivalent to the classic metric $d(x, y) = |x - y|$, so $D_φ$ is well-defined.

---

It is natural to assume that $φ$ and $f$ are derivable to analyze $D_φ f$, but the cases where $φ \in \D$ yields the most intuitions. For $φ \in \D$ and any derivable $f$,\begin{align*}
D_φ f(x) &= \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial h}(f(x +_φ h) -_φ f(x)) \right|_{h = 0}\\
&=\bigl( (φ^{-1})'(φ(f(x +_φ h)) - φ(f(x))) · φ'(f(x +_φ h)) · f'(x +_φ h) ·\\
&\mathrel{\phantom=} (φ^{-1})'(φ(x) + φ(h)) · φ'(h) \bigr)\Bigr|_{h = 0}\\
&= \color{red}{ \frac{1}{φ'(0)} } · φ'(f(x)) · f'(x) · \color{blue}{ \frac{1}{φ'(x)} } · \color{red}{ φ'(0) } \tag{1}\\
&= \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} = \frac{(φ \circ f)'(x)}{φ'(x)},
\end{align*}
so $D_φ f = \dfrac{D(φ \circ f)}{Dφ}$, where $D$ is the classic derivative operator. Note that this formula also implies that diffeomorphism in the classic sense is equivalent to that in the sense of $D_φ$.

Now, in order to show that $(\R, +)$ cannot be differentiated from $(\R, +_φ)$ by how their derivative operators interact with other non-classic plus operations, define\begin{gather*}
x +_{φ_1, φ_2} y = φ_2^{-1}(φ_2(x) +_{φ_1} φ_2(y)),\\
D_{φ_1, φ_2}f(x) = \lim_{h → 0} \frac{1}{h} (f(x +_{φ_1, φ_2} h) -_{φ_1, φ_2} f(x))
\end{gather*}
for any $φ_1, φ_2 \in \D$. Since$$
x +_{φ_1, φ_2} y = φ_2^{-1}(φ_1^{-1}(φ_1(φ_2(x)) + φ_1(φ_2(y)))) = x +_{φ_1 \circ φ_2} y.
$$
then $+_{φ_1, φ_2} = +_{φ_1 \circ φ_2}$ and$$
D_{φ_1, φ_2}f = D_{φ_1 \circ φ_2}f = \frac{D(φ_1 \circ φ_2 \circ f)}{D(φ_1 \circ φ_2)} = \frac{D(φ_1 \circ φ_2 \circ f) / Dφ_1}{D(φ_1 \circ φ_2) / Dφ_1} = \frac{D_{φ_1}(φ_2 \circ f)}{D_{φ_1}φ_2}.
$$
This formula on $(\R, +_{φ_1})$ is just the same as $D_{\id, φ_2} f = \dfrac{D_{\id}(φ_2 \circ f)}{D_{\id} φ_2}$, or $D_{φ_2} f = \dfrac{D(φ_2 \circ f)}{Dφ_2}$, on $(\R, +)$.

---

The situation gets much more complicated even if the condition $φ \in \D$ is simply relaxed as $φ \in \D_0$. Now the definition of $\D_0$ ensures that the blue term in (1) is always defined for $x ≠ 0$, but the red terms suggest that the simple chain rule fails if $φ'(0) = 0$ or $φ'(0)$ does not exist. This suggests that $0$ is a special point for $D_φ f$.

More specifically, for $x ≠ 0$, since\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom=} \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial k}φ(f(φ^{-1}(φ(x) + k))) \right|_{k = 0}\\
&= \bigl( φ'(f(φ^{-1}(φ(x) + k))) · f'(φ^{-1}(φ(x) + k)) · (φ^{-1})'(φ(x) + k) \bigr)\Bigr|_{k = 0}\\
&= φ'(f(x)) · f'(x) · \frac{1}{φ'(x)} = \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)},
\end{align*}
then\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{h} (f(x +_φ h) -_φ f(x)) = \frac{1}{h} φ^{-1}\paren{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} · φ(h) + o(φ(h)) }\ (h → 0). \tag{2}
\end{gather*}
Therefore $D_φf(x)$ exists if the limit of the RHS of (2) exists. Even though (2) is not valid for $x = 0$, the factor $φ'(f(x))$ in (2) implies that whether $f(0) = 0$ or $f(0) ≠ 0$ makes a difference for $D_φ f(0)$ if $φ'(0) = 0$ since there is a factor $φ'(x)$ in the denominator and derivatives are [Darboux functions](https://planetmath.org/GeneralizedDarbouxFunction). Below are two explicit examples.

*Example 1:* $φ(x) = \sgn(x) |x|^a$ ($a > 0$, $a ≠ 1$). Since $φ$ is multiplicative, then for $x ≠ 0$, (2) implies that\begin{align*}
D_φf(x) &= \lim_{h → 0} \frac{1}{h} φ^{-1}\paren{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} · φ(h) + o(φ(h)) }\\
&= \lim_{h → 0} φ^{-1}\paren{ \frac{1}{φ(h)} \paren{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} · φ(h) + o(φ(h)) } }\\
&= \lim_{h → 0} φ^{-1}\paren{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} + o(1) }\\
&= φ^{-1}\paren{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} } = \sgn(f'(x)) \abs{ \frac{f(x)}{x} }^{\frac{a - 1}{a}} |f'(x)|^{\frac{1}{a}}.
\end{align*}
Again $0$ can be seen to be a special point because of the factor $|f(x)|^{\frac{a - 1}{a}}$ in the above expression.

*Example 2:* $φ(x) = \begin{cases} x\exp\paren{-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}; & x ≠ 0 \\ 0; & x = 0 \end{cases}$. Note that for any $c \in (0, 1)$, $φ(ch) = o(φ(h))$ ($h → 0$). For $x ≠ 0$, if $f(x) ≠ 0$ and $f'(x) ≠ 0$, then for any $ε \in (0, 1)$,$$
φ((1 - ε)h) = o(φ(h)),\quad φ(h) = o(φ((1 + ε)h)),\quad (h → 0)
$$
thus there exists $δ > 0$ such that for $h \in (-δ, δ) \setminus \{0\}$,$$
|φ((1 - ε)h)| < \abs{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} · φ(h) + o(φ(h)) } < |φ((1 + ε)h)|,\\
$$
so$$
1 - ε < \frac{1}{h} φ^{-1}\paren{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} · φ(h) + o(φ(h)) } < 1 + ε.
$$
Therefore (2) implies that$$
D_φf(x) = \lim_{h → 0} \frac{1}{h} φ^{-1}\paren{ \frac{φ'(f(x)) f'(x)}{φ'(x)} · φ(h) + o(φ(h)) } = 1.
$$
If $f(x) = 0$, then\begin{align*}
D_φf(x) &= \lim_{h → 0} \frac{1}{h} φ^{-1}(φ(f(φ^{-1}(φ(x) + φ(h)))) - φ(0))\\
&= \lim_{h → 0} \frac{1}{h} f(φ^{-1}(φ(x) + φ(h)))\\
&= \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial h}(f(φ^{-1}(φ(x) + φ(h)))) \right|_{h = 0}\\
&= \bigl( f'(φ^{-1}(φ(x) + φ(h))) · (φ^{-1})'(φ(x) + φ(h)) · φ'(h) \bigr)\Bigr|_{h = 0}\\
&= f'(x) · \frac{1}{φ'(x)} · φ'(0) = 0.
\end{align*}
This example shows that if $φ$ varies too slowly near $0$, then $D_φ$ will almost wipe out any information of the functions it applies to.

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate answer, but that still does not to clarify my primary confusion. Am I correct in assuming that $(\Bbb R, +_{\varphi_a}, \cdot)$ is a field, if $\varphi_a$ is like in your Example 1?

Comment: @Ilya For $φ$ of this particular form, it's indeed a field due to the multiplicativity of $φ$: for any $x,y\in\mathbb R$,\begin{gather*}ax+_φay=φ^{-1}(φ(ax)+φ(ay))=φ^{-1}(φ(a)(φ(x)+φ(y)))\\=φ^{-1}(φ(a))φ^{-1}(φ(x)+φ(y))=aφ^{-1}(φ(x)+φ(y))=a(x+_φy).\end{gather*}P.S.: I missed this comment since there were a bunch of incoming messages.

Comment: Np! So, we agreed to have a family of fields indexed by $\alpha$. Let's assume, we are just given this family with no other context. Just a set a family of operations on it. All the resulting fields are mutually homeomorphic as fields and as topologies they generate. Now, I'm telling that exactly *one* of elements of this family does not require the function to preserve zero (same for all fields) in order to be differentiable at zero. How do you find, which of the elements satisfies this property and *why other elements do not*.

Comment: Hello! Would you agree with deleting [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=60853491#60853491) as per [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=59988423#59988423)? Thanks! You weren't pingable there but I thought you would want to know about it.